Is there an option to prevent Hardhat from slowing down, e.g., by limiting Hardhat's history?
I need to run thousands of transactions for my test suite, but after a while, my local Hardhat node becomes very slow. How can I make it faster?
Would using the --max-memory option help? Can I set it in hardhat.config.js? I’m using Brownie to run my Hardhat node.
